# Как посмотреть структуру элементов на форме?

Tags: winforms, controls

Есть ли возможность визуально увидеть структуру расположения элементов (controls) на форме?

Задача связана с тем, чтобы быстро определить во что вложен определенный control.

Comment: Пробовали правой кнопки мыши открыть контекстное меню модуля в загруженном в MSVS проекте и из него выбрать пункт "открыть в конструкторе"?

Comment: Можно просто также посмотреть в коде, к какому объекту он добавлен в коллекцию контролов с помощью метода Add.

Comment: Главное меню -> View -> Other windows -> Document outline

Comment: @А.Терентьев или оформите ответ как ответ, или удалите вопрос :)